# VBA Excel modify file and keep same checksum

Tags: excel, vba

I saw different ways of creating checksum for some plain text file but I would like to be able to change mentioned file contents but in same time to keep already known (set) checksum by filling rest of the file with necessary characters. I got this idea when long years ago found some app (ATARI computer I think) able to make disk boot-able after change of its ID, if checksum of boot sector is $1234. Is it possible to achieve in VBA? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide your workaround, That will help some to help you on this.

Comment: This sounds a _lot_ like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you're trying to achieve with the checksum, and why do you want it to remain the same even though you've changed the file that creates it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I would like to be able to change mentioned file contents but in same time to keep already known (set) checksum by filling rest of the file with necessary characters.*

You can't do that, at least not with any hashing algorithm worth its salt (crypto pun not intended... I swear!). Well you could, *in theory*, but then there's no telling how many characters (and how much time and disk space!) you're going to need to add in order to get *the* hash collision that yields exactly the same hash as the original file.

What you're asking is basically defeating the entire purpose of a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).

I don't think that ATARI computer used SHA-1 hashing (160 bits), let alone the SHA-256 or SHA-512 (or 128-bit MD5), or any other algorithm in common use today.

You could implement some of the lower-bitness [checksum algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions), but the smaller the hash, the higher the risk of a hash collision - and the easier it is to get a hash that collides with your checksum value, the more meaningless the checksum is.

*By definition*, a hashing function isn't reversible, and a salted, cryptographic hash will not even produce the same ouptut given two *identical* inputs. I'm not familiar with checksum, but if I had to implement one, I would probably go with a high-bitness cryptographic hashing algorithm, in order to reduce the risk of a hash collision down to statistical insignificance.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to figure out some other approach in order to achieve some acceptable solution.

Comment: @Isma the only sane solution is to accept that different content means a different content hash / checksum value...